# How do I concatenate strings in NETBEANS with + signs and escape codes?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, netbeans-8

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
String output = "If you borrow" + currencyFormatter.format(loanAmount);
    +" at an interest rate of" + rate + %;
    +"\nfor" + years;
    +",you will pay" + totalInterest + "in interest.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the semicolons before the end of your concatenation.

```
String output = "If you borrow" + currencyFormatter.format(loanAmount)
    +" at an interest rate of" + rate + "%"
    +"\nfor" + years
    +",you will pay" + totalInterest + "in interest.";
```

I also recommend that you move the concatenation operator to the end of the line rather than the start of the line. It's a minor stylistic preference...

```
String output = "If you borrow" + currencyFormatter.format(loanAmount) +
    " at an interest rate of" + rate + "%" + 
    "\nfor" + years +
    ",you will pay" + totalInterest + "in interest.";
```

Finally, you may notice that you are missing some white-spaces when you try printing that string. The [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method helps with that (also see the documentation for [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)). It's also faster than doing lots of concatenations.

```
String output = String.format(
    "If you borrow %s at an interest rate of %d%%\nfor %d years, you will pay %d in interest.", currencyFormatter.format(loanAmount), rate, years, totalInterest
);
```